# Sharing values between states in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I share the variable "demo" between all of my states in angular? I've tried to do this by creating a 'mainController' and placing it inside of my states along with another controller in the 'view' like shown below. But I keep getting an error saying that 'demo' is not defined when I try `console.log(demo);` in my states.

My Main Controller

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope,$http,$state,$window,$timeout) {
  var demo = "works";
})
```

How I've tried to intergrate that 'mainController' within my states **alongside** a controller in my 'view' **(NOTE: I've closed the brackets on the example I'm showing you, there's just a lot of javascript below this script)**

```
.state('checkIn',{
    controller:'mainController',
    url:'/checkIn',
    views: {
        'main':{
            templateUrl: 'templates/checkIn.html',

            controller: function($scope,$http,$state,$window,$timeout){
              console.log(demo);
```

The rest of my javascript

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ui.router','service'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs).
    // The reason we default this to hidden is that native apps don't usually show an accessory bar, at
    // least on iOS. It's a dead giveaway that an app is using a Web View. However, it's sometimes
    // useful especially with forms, though we would prefer giving the user a little more room
    // to interact with the app.
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
  }
  if (window.StatusBar) {
      // Set the statusbar to use the default style, tweak this to
      // remove the status bar on iOS or change it to use white instead of dark colors.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }
});
});

app.controller('mainController', function ($scope,$http,$state,$window,$timeout) {
  var demo = "works";
})

app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInter');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')

    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        controller:'mainController',
        url:'/home',
        views: {
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',

            }
        }
    })

    .state('signUp',{
        controller:'mainController',
        url:'/signUp',
        views: {
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/signUp.html',

                controller: function($scope,$http,$timeout,$state){
                    $scope.register = function(){
                        $scope.serverMsg =false;

                        $http.post('/signUp', $scope.newUser).then(function(data){
                            $scope.serverMsg = data.data;
                            if($scope.serverMsg.success == true){
                                $timeout(function(){
                                    $state.go('login');
                                }, 2000);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .state('login',{
        controller:'mainController',
        url:'/login',
        views: {
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                controller: function($scope,$http,$timeout,$state,$window){
                    $scope.setCurrentUser = function(user){
                        $scope.currentUser = user;
                        console.log($scope.currentUser);
                    }
                    $scope.serverMsg = false;

                    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/users').then(function({ data: users }) {
                        $scope.users = users;
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .state('checkIn',{
        controller:'mainController',
        url:'/checkIn',
        views: {
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/checkIn.html',
                // resolve: {

                // },
                controller: function($scope,$http,$state,$window,$timeout){
                  console.log(demo);
                  var today = new Date();
                  var hour = today.getHours();
                  var minute = today.getMinutes();
                  var meridianPlaceHolder = today.getHours();
                  meridianPlaceHolder = AmPm(meridianPlaceHolder);
                  minute = checkTime(minute);
                  hour = checkHour(hour);

                  //Handles Times
                  function AmPm(i){
                    if(i < 12){
                      return "AM";
                    }
                    else{
                      return "PM";
                    }
                  }

                  function checkHour(i){
                    if (i > 12){
                      i = i - 12;
                    };
                    return i;
                  }

                  function checkTime(i) {
                      if (i < 10) {
                        i = "0" + i
                      };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
                      return i;
                  }

                  //var arrivalTime = document.getElementById("arrivalTime");

                  //Sets a default input value for the arrivalTime
                  $scope.arrivalTime = hour + ":" + minute + " " + meridianPlaceHolder;


                  //arrivalTime.setAttribute("value", hour + ":" + minute + " " + meridianPlaceHolder);

                  //Checks whether or not the user has chosen a latop
                  var laptopQuery = false;
                  $('#yesLaptop').click(function(){
                    laptopQuery = true
                  });

                  $('#noLaptop').click(function(){
                    laptopQuery = false
                  });

                  //Handles the Inputs of the Check In Page
                  $scope.submit = function(){
                    $scope.serverMsg = false;
                    console.log("Submitting Check In...");

                    //Assigns a Random Laptop
                    var laptops = ["laptop2","laptop3","laptop4","laptop5","laptop6","laptop7","laptop8","laptop9","laptop10","laptop11","laptop12","laptop13","laptop14","laptop15","laptop16","laptop17","laptop18","laptop19","laptop20","laptop21","laptop22","laptop23","laptop24"];
                    var laptop = laptops.splice([Math.floor(Math.random()*laptops.length)], 1);

                    //Retrieves input values
                    var timeLogArrival = document.getElementById("arrivalTime").value;
                    var timeLogDepature = document.getElementById("depatureTime").value;
                    var reasonForVisit = document.getElementById("reasonForVisit").value;

                    //Logs data, isn't currently working on monogo
                    console.log("Time of Arrival: " + timeLogArrival);
                    console.log("Time of Departure: " + timeLogDepature);
                    console.log("Reason for Visit: " + reasonForVisit);
                    //Displays whether or not a user checke out a laptop or not
                    if (laptopQuery){
                    console.log("Your Laptop: " + laptop);
                    alert("Your Laptop: " + laptop);
                    }
                    else{
                      console.log("You didn't check out a laptop");
                    }
                    // var laptopUpdateQuery = {laptopId:laptop};
                    // var userQuery = {'name':$scope.currentUser.name};
                    // user.findOneandUpdate(userQuery,laptopUpdateQuery,function(err,doc){
                    //     err ? console.log(err) : alert("success");
                    // })
                    $http.put('/check',$scope.currentUser).then(function(data){
                          $scope.serverMsg = data.data;
                          if($scope.serverMsg.success == true){
                            $timeout(function(){
                                console.log("user data updated");
                                $state.go('home');
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    });
                  }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
});

// this is for the phone number
app.directive('phoneInput', function($filter, $browser) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var listener = function() {
                var value = $element.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                $element.val($filter('tel')(value, false));
            };

            // This runs when we update the text field
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                return viewValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0,10);
            });

            // This runs when the model gets updated on the scope directly and keeps our view in sync
            ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
                $element.val($filter('tel')(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, false));
            };

            $element.bind('change', listener);
            $element.bind('keydown', function(event) {
                var key = event.keyCode;
                // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
                // This lets us support copy and paste too
                if (key == 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)){
                    return;
                }
                $browser.defer(listener); // Have to do this or changes don't get picked up properly
            });

            $element.bind('paste cut', function() {
                $browser.defer(listener);
            });
        }
    };
});

app.filter('tel', function () {
    return function (tel) {
        console.log(tel);
        if (!tel) { return ''; }

        var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

        if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
            return tel;
        }

        var country, city, number;

        switch (value.length) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            city = value;
            break;

            default:
            city = value.slice(0, 3);
            number = value.slice(3);
        }

        if(number){
            if(number.length>3){
                number = number.slice(0, 3) + '-' + number.slice(3,7);
            }
            else{
                number = number;
            }

            return ("(" + city + ") " + number).trim();
        }
        else{
            return "(" + city;
        }

    };
});

//Javascript for the Date to show in the input field by default
// Time


 // controller: function($scope,$http,$timeout,$state,$window){
 //                    $scope.login = function(){
 //                        $scope.serverMsg =false;

 //                        $http.get('mongodb://localhost:27017/cubeData', $scope.user.name).then(function(data){
 //                            $scope.serverMsg = data.data;

 //                            if($scope.serverMsg.success == true){

 //                                $timeout(function(){
 //                                    $state.go('checkIn');
 //                                }, 2000);
 //                            }
 //                        });
 //                    }
 //                }
 //            }
 //        }
 //    })


  // $scope.loggingOut = false;
                        // $scope.logout = function(){
                        //     $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
                        //     $scope.loggingOut = true;
                        //     $timeout(function () {
                        //         $state.go('signUp');
                        //     }, 3000);

                        // }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, in descending order of correctness.

**First** - Create a factory/service/value/constant within the app to hold this shared value and include it everywhere you need to access the value, preferably with a getter/setter for the value.

In the following example, it would be preferable to get the values by including `myService` and calling `myService.getMyObject()`, but still 
possible to simply use `myService.myValue` e.g. -

```
app.service('myService', function() { 
    var service = {
        myValue: 'some value',
        myObject: { foo: 'bar' },
        getMyObject: function() { return service.myObject; },
        setMyObject: function(data) { service.myObject = data; }
    };
    return service;
});
```

**Second** - (This is kind of a hack and not a good practice) is to store the value on the $rootScope. This makes it globally available - in controllers, services, and templates. It's easy to pollute using this method, so option 1 is preferred.

**Third** - (not recommended) You could do it the way you are trying, but it's not advisable. You'd have to either use the `controllerAs` syntax defining your controllers and access the value through `$scope.main.demo`, or without controllerAs, through `$scope.$parent.demo` <-- this gets ugly and confusing fast, depending on nesting.

Comment: Second I would say that is not recommended as well, it is a really bad practice. 
By the way, to improve the First way, considering that he needs only a single variable across all the application, what about using a value and use decorator to set it? 



`app.value('myVar', 'Default Value');`


`$provide.decorator('myVar', function ($delegate) {
    return $delegate + ' and same value more';
});`

Comment: Agreed, the second way is also not recommended, but is less bad than the third option :P

As for the value, that's a great solution for providing a single value. If that's the goal (and I suppose that's the question, specifically) then that's all they need. 

Assuming OP would like to have access to multiple values or complex types, a service is a safer/more broadly applicable solution.

Comment: yeah totally agree, if he is going to share multiple things, a service is the best solution. 
Otherwise for a single variable he can just use a value, if dynamic, constant if constant

Answer (score 0):

Create a service to share data across your application

Answer (score 0):

As @LouisK pointed out, the first way it's the suggested one. I would say also that you can consider the angular `value` too if you want to share just one single variable, otherwise services are the right way.

```
app.value('myVar', 'Default Value');
```

In order to change it:

```
$provide.decorator('myVar', function ($delegate) { return $delegate + ' and same value more'; });
```

Then simply inject `myVar` where you need.